# Problem in Coverage with Karma / Webpack / Istanbul

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, webpack, code-coverage, karma-webpack

perhaps you can help me out. Im not a big expert with karma so perhaps I miss something.

My Project looks like this:

- js/libs --> Saved all libs I need
- js/src/[ComponentName] --> Saved all custom scripts in own component folders

Within the component folders are Directives, Controllers from AngularJS and also the Unit-Tests (saves as xxx.spec.js) for them.

karma.conf.js (saved in root of project)

```
config.set({
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    webpack: webpackConfig, // See below
    files: [
        'js/index.js',
        'js/src/**/*.spec.js'
    ],
    preprocessors: {
        'js/index.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
    },

    reporters: ['mocha', 'coverage-istanbul'],
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
        reports: ['html', 'text-summary' ],
        fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
        dir: path.join(__dirname, 'coverage'),
    },
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: true,
});
```

webpack.config.js (saved in root of project)

```
{
    mode: 'development',
    entry: '',
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        chunkFilename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
    },
    module: {
       rules: [
            {
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {presets: ['env']}
            },
            {
                use: {loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader'},
                exclude: [
                    /node_modules|index\.js|\.spec\.js$/,
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/lib')
                ],
                enforce: 'post'
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map'
}
```

So in general:

I have a source folder with all JS Files (including the Unit-Tests)

I have a build process which builds the necessary JS files into the build path

I have index.js files which required the source files

And I have a coverage in a separate subfolder for the unit tests.

The unit-tests run successful and the coverage (istanbul HTML) is generated. When I look into the coverage, I see the percentage correctly ... But if I take a look at the details of one file, there are no markings for the coverage and the missing code lines (the green and red markings).
And also the detail list of the coverage shows me every source file twice.

Do someone have any clue why this happens?

Current coverage state:

[image]